# UniTime keep creating an error when i run it with my Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i need to use UniTime on Docker but it doesn't work properly, i keep getting an error when i run it.

The error I get:

```
ERROR  TaskExecutorService -> Failed to check for tasks: The session factory has not been initialized (or an error occured during initialization)
java.lang.RuntimeException: The session factory has not been initialized (or an error occured during initialization)
    at org.unitime.timetable.model.base._BaseRootDAO.getSessionFactory(_BaseRootDAO.java:111)
    at org.unitime.timetable.model.base._BaseRootDAO.getSession(_BaseRootDAO.java:151)
    at org.unitime.timetable.model.base._BaseRootDAO.createNewSession(_BaseRootDAO.java:141)
    at org.unitime.timetable.server.script.TaskExecutorService.checkForQueuedTasks(TaskExecutorService.java:67)
    at org.unitime.timetable.server.script.TaskExecutorService$TaskExecutor.run(TaskExecutorService.java:162)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8

EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apt-utils && \
    apt-get install -y default-mysql-server
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
ENV TOMCAT8_GROUP=tomcat8
ENV TOMCAT8_USER=tomcat8
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar && \
    cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib/ && \
    wget https://github.com/UniTime/unitime/releases/download/v4.4.140/unitime-4.4_bld140.zip && \
    unzip unitime-4.4_bld140.zip -d unitime && \
    /etc/init.d/mysql start && \
    mysql -uroot -f <unitime/doc/mysql/schema.sql && \
    mysql -uroot -f <unitime/doc/mysql/schema.sql && \
    mysql -utimetable -punitime <unitime/doc/mysql/blank-data.sql && \
    mkdir /usr/local/tomcat/data && \
    useradd tomcat && \
    chown tomcat /usr/local/tomcat/data && \
    cp unitime/web/UniTime.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for help on this. Here are some of the changes I had to make in the UniTime files to work with Docker Deploy. Some of the lib updates are specific to Java 8.

0. Un-comment the mysql connectivity section in the UniTime pom.xml
   https://github.com/UniTime/unitime/blob/master/pom.xml#L275-L282
   Update the pom's mysql.version to the version you are using.
1. In UniTime .project add com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse references

```
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.gwtplugins.gdt.eclipse.core.webAppProjectValidator</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
...
        <nature>com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</nature>
    </natures>
...
```

2. In UniTime Documentation/Database/MySQL/schema.sql find the docker equivalent of localhost (127..?) or expand the timetable user scope (for testing).

```
...
drop user timetable@localhost;
drop user IF EXISTS timetable@localhost;

create user timetable@localhost identified by 'unitime';
/* for Docker */
create user timetable@'%' identified by 'unitime';

grant all on timetable.* to timetable@localhost;
/* for Docker */
grant all on timetable.* to timetable@'%';
...
```

3. In UniTime JavaSource/hibernate.cfg.xml add additional hibernate params

```
...

   <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://database:3306/timetable?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=TRUE</property>
...
    <!-- for Java 8-11 TSLv1.2 SSL 3 -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.verifyServerCertificate">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.requireSSL">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useSSL">false</property>
    <!-- End of MySQL Configuration -->
...
```

4. I used a docker-compose.yml file to set the tomcat and docker config.